# karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.1.0 requires a peer of jasmine@>=3 but none is installed.

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

After upgrading jasmine-core to version 3.1.0, I also wanted to upgrade karma-jasmine-html-reporter to the latest version 1.1.0

```
npm i --no-optional
```

results in

> npm WARN karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.1.0 requires a peer of
>   jasmine@>=3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies
>   yourself.

My package.json with devDepenencies

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.8",
    "@types/node": "10.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.1.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-ie-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.1.0",
    "protractor": "~5.3.2",
    "tslint": "~5.10.0",
    "typescript": "2.7.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8"
}
```

Am I wrong assuming jasmine-core == @jasmine? Is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This warning says that your package `karma-jasmine-html-reporter` has peer dependency to `jasmine` version `>=3`. Basically if you install latest version of `jasmine` that warning will be removed. Currently latest version of `jasmine` is 3.1.0 and if you install that version your issue will disappear.

You can fix this warning by running `npm install --save-dev jasmine`.

`jasmine` and `jasmine-core` are not same packages.  Please see comparison between those two packages [here](https://npmcompare.com/compare/jasmine,jasmine-core,jasmine-node,mocha).